# AlchemyAPI Usage

Tags: php, nlp, alchemyapi

I am searching and trying to learn Alchemy API. However, I am not able to use that API with PHP. Can anybody tell me how to use this API? For instance I would like to categorize the text so I will use textGetCategory PHP method. How to use this method in my PHP files I want to know this.
Thanks.

Comment: What *is* AlchemyAPI? Some links would probably be helpful.

Comment: http://www.alchemyapi.com/ introduces API. It is an NLP project for information extraction. May be a better API suggested, I just found this one and basically it makes what i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a simple wrapper around the APIs they provide via their PHP classes, maybe you can start from this code and add the methods that you require.

```
class SimpleAlchemyAPI {

  protected static $instance = null;

  public static function getInstance() {
    if(is_null(self::$instance)) {
      $class = __CLASS__;
      self::$instance = new $class;
    }

    return self::$instance;
  }

  public $api = null;

  protected function __construct() {
    require_once('./AlchemyAPI.php');
    require_once('./AlchemyAPIParams.php');
    $this->api = new AlchemyAPI;
    $this->api->setAPIKey("your_api_key");
  }

  public function getTitle($url) {
    $result = json_decode($this->api->URLGetTitle($url, 'json'), true);
    return $result['status'] == 'OK' ? $result['title'] : null;
  }

  public function getContent($url) {
    $result = json_decode($this->api->URLGetText($url, 'json'), true);
    return $result['status'] == 'OK' ? $result['text'] : null;
  }
}
```

Just change the paths in the `__construct` as well as adding your API key and you're set to use it.

```
SimpleAlchemyAPI::getInstance()
  ->getTitle('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083656/alchemyapi-usage');
```

Comment: That works really well for me. Just please be over here I can have several troubles about that api and will be pleased to get answer from you: ). Thanks!!!

Comment: @gencay I'm not sure I will be able to give you more information about the API because this is all I've used it for (maybe even tags if I remember well).

Answer (score 1):

alchemy provides an api which can be used to find entity extraction , text extraction sentiment of a text or html and so on. **http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/**here you can find all the details related to alchemy api.
and the php-sdk is available on **https://github.com/AlchemyAPI/alchemyapi_php/**